# Calculating a correction factor

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, correlation

I have a variable that I suspect is influenced by Temperature, and I'd like to calculate a correction factor that accounts for the effect of temperature.

So give a time series of temperature data:

```
Temp<-c(23.545, 23.475, 23.382, 23.328, 23.251, 23.247, 23.241, 23.227, 23.146,
 23.133, 23.127, 23.567, 23.561, 23.521, 23.496, 23.348, 23.274, 23.270,
 23.258, 23.244, 23.158, 23.152, 23.132, 23.123, 23.083, 23.025, 22.999,
 22.666, 22.330, 22.072, 21.794, 21.532, 21.063, 20.742, 19.183, 18.556,
 17.165, 15.233, 13.844, 12.818, 12.236, 11.914)
```

And the variable in question:

```
var<-c(0.080, -0.003, -0.018, -0.035,  0.005, -0.023,  0.080,  0.035,  0.065,
 -0.055, -0.030, -0.038,  0.010,  0.013,  0.018, -0.033, -0.028,  0.105,
 -0.085,  0.010,  0.018, -0.065, -0.048, -0.013, -0.103, -0.013,  0.002,
 0.053, -0.018,  0.080,  0.057,  0.083,  0.060,  0.085,  0.158,  0.155,
 0.232,  0.245,  0.390,  0.400,  0.568,  0.508)
```

I can plot the two together to see the effect of temp on var

```
plot(Temp,var)
```

I have one Temp observation at 22.330 that I know is correct. So I'd like to adjust the var data based on some sort of correction factor by either assuming:

A - All the var values are close to the same value, and most of the variance is due to temp

B- The point at 22.330 is correct, and values above and below should be corrected accordingly

Comment: If you would like to fit a straight line to the data and also have the regression line pass through the 22.330 point, use a weighted regression where all of the weights are 1.0 - except - at the 22.330 point, which you should give a very large weight such as 10,000. This will effectively force the regression through this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps here is a starting point.

Let's start by fitting a linear model `var ~ Temp`

```
fit <- lm(var ~ Temp)
```

I don't see a point for using a weighted linear model, other than artificially forcing the model through a/multiple specific point(s). The data are what they are, and a linear model of the form `var ~ Temp` will characterise a general linear dependence between `var` and `Temp`.

Let's combine data in a `data.frame`, and add a `Time` column as well as the residuals from the the linear model fit.

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(Time = 1:length(Temp), Temp, var, resid = fit$residuals)
```

We show the following plots:

```
library(gridExtra)
gg1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Time, var)) + geom_point()
gg2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Temp, var)) + geom_point()
gg3 <- ggplot(df, aes(Time, resid)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, gg3, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

1. The left panel shows the dependence of `var` on `Time`.
2. The middle panel shows the dependence of `var` on `Temp`, which you hypothesise exists.
3. The right panel shows the residual effect of `var` on `Time` after we corrected for the linear dependence of `var` on `Temp`.

In other words, you can consider the residuals as the `var` values corrected for `Temp`. They characterise the variability in `var` that is not explained by `Temp`.